# How to share code between separate clojurescripts in the same project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a project that compiles 2 scripts used in 2 pages of the app:

```
 :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-path "src-cljs/search",
                       :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/cljs/search.js" }}
                      {:source-path "src-cljs/view",
                       :compiler { :output-to "resources/public/cljs/view.js"}}
                      ]
```

I have code common for both scripts. How to share this code? The only way I have found is through a separate Clojure project - I execute 'lein install' on it and it is available to my ClojuresScript code as any other third-party library.

I've noticed the crossovers, but they are for sharing code between Clojure and ClojureScript. I don't need the shared code in Clojure. So I could use crossovers but that would leave me with some unneeded Clojure code in the end jar. Not a big issue but still not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [article](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/second-edition/tutorial-06.md) I afforded the same issue. You're solution is the one I called "Easy made complex" solution, because of duplication. The second one which I called the "Simple made easy" should be the one you're looking for.