# Sharing code between separate scripts (outputs)

Tags: clojurescript

I have a project which is not intended to be a single page application, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to share code for common functionality between different script outputs.

For example I may have a stores.js target, and a items.js target built from cljs/stores and cljs/items respectively, but both have some overlapping functionality (say tables with editable cells).

So far the solutions I've come up with are either to symlink common file(s) into both directories that implement the functionality, which I find aesthetically displeasing, but should actually work fine, or to extract the common functionality into a separate package and make the project depend on it. That however involves either requiring developers to setup both repositories and install the dependency locally, or setup a maven server.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429093/1593947) answer from 2012 seems to suggest I should simply do away with multiple targets and instead initialize the functionality I want on the correct page, but it seems to me that having the functionality for the entire site in a single file would make the resulting javascript much larger than it needs to be, increasing the page load time, especially given that I will have more than 2 pages.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you have to symlink the common dependencies ? Can't you put them in another cljs file, and use/require/import it from both stores.js and items.js ? If you're troubled by duplications in the html, maybe you could "generate" the html with templates on the server-side to avoid copy-pasting ? Could you describe your hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out the solution is pretty simple, and actually should have been clear from the cljsbuild docs, but I wasn't seeing it. It took trying to reply to @phtrivier for me to actually see what I was missing.

The solution is to use multiple source paths in my project.clj file. So a simple example would look like so:

```
{:builds [{:source-paths ["src/cljs/items"
                          "src/cljs/shared"]
           :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/items.js"
                      :optimizations :simple
                      :pretty-print true}
           :jar true}
          {:source-paths ["src/cljs/stores"
                          "src/cljs/shared"]
           :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/stores.js"
                      :optimizations :simple
                      :pretty-print true}}]}
```

from there it's simple:

`src/cljs/shared/shared.cljs`

```
(ns shared)

(defn common []
  "Hello World")
```

`src/cljs/items/items.cljs`

```
(ns items
  (:require [shared :refer [common]]))

(.log js/console (common))
```

`src/cljs/stores/stores.cljs`

```
(ns stores
  (:require [shared :refer [common]]))

(js/alert (common))
```

`items.js` and `stores.js` will be their own separate files both containing the shared code.